# R weird error when creating large ff objects

Tags: r, memory, bigdata, ff

I'm trying to create some large ff objects. According to [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html), this shouldn't be an issue:

```
ff <- ff(3, dim=c(10000, 4000, 70), filename="test1.ff", vmode="single")
```

This gives me the little helpful error:

```
Error in ff(3, dim = c(10000, 4000, 70), filename = "test1.ff", vmode = "single") : 
  (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
 1: ff(3, dim = c(10000, 4000, 70), filename = "test1.ff", vmode = "single")
 2: .signalSimpleWarning("NAs introduced by coercion", quote(ff(3, dim = c(10000, 4000, 70), filename = "test1.ff", vmode = "single")))
 3: withRestarts({
    .Internal(.signalCondition(simpleWarning(msg, call), msg, call))
    .Internal(.dfltWarn(msg, call))
}, muffleWarning = function() NULL)
 4: withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1]])
 5: doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
```

Creating a smaller one, works well:

```
ff <- ff(3, dim=c(10000, 3000, 70), filename="test1.ff", vmode="single")
```

Am I missing something ? Is there a limitation on size of the array (length of vector) ?

Comment: For starters, I wouldn't call your object `ff`. `ff` is the function you're trying to call, so you will at the least get some unexpected results by renaming a function to an ff object.

Comment: 10000*4000*70 > .Machine$integer.max, you can not create vector of length > 2.1 billion